# Error in parsing JSON data (Google places API)

Tags: android, google-places-api, httpurlconnection, json

I am using Google places API in android and I am damn sure that my URL generated via code is correct.

**Below is the code I am using to fetch the JSON data:**

```
   StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(theUrl);
                    URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()), 8);
                    String line;
                    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        content.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    Log.d("CONTENT!!!!!" ,content.toString());
                    bufferedReader.close();
                }catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return content.toString();
```

**However, I get an error :**

```
                                                           org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of null
```

**Any idea where am I going wrong ?**

Below is the JSON data, I am trying to parse:

```
 {
    html_attributions: [ ],
    next_page_token: "CoQC_wAAABa8XQ8m02lmj8Z367BHKq-rE6tMbECc4CHOmIK_ylEdUXQFd4G1ch2Pha8L0XMclpq-f3YhbfyljleFMJ6dedT-xlCMmeEVYdwrUiAQIMSNpn7Ot7FTwPLhv-DaBj51wrGwow5fnt8paHdIw_Vq_Z9zLVL-LtQALoKLfTkVOIfo5PDJ_oqStI7kDQE1abA69pNhP2NMalyt408nAHkPYUiJSJZmW3d6Nm2-OGbeAdpyBtCm6mr6ONdQ-9A-mdp37k7HKfmnDbiOvUf-RuY2a0JCPkQgO2US7JoMFm5BgcgSi1iEeLJxHntilFnqHRwy6XcWGrIbAj-KDa7o1OZSD78SENGN0beZDJ3wdKqoB6m_RdgaFD_obOV9TPRGHVm_pY36aDDgLiiy",
    results: [
    {
    geometry: {
    location: {
    lat: 19.072002,
    lng: 72.99866829999999
    }
    },
    icon: "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
    id: "46e58e9806d2615559ddcfb8cd306a494e9d26bd",
    name: "मैक्डॉनल्ड",
    opening_hours: {
    open_now: true,
    weekday_text: [ ]
    },
    photos: [
    {
    height: 949,
    html_attributions: [
    "<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/110703537406192340959/photos">vijay kadam</a>"
    ],
    photo_reference: "CoQBcwAAAJ6MLUY0eHh04ohpj5ZYklI6lpOcqZ5ZdYmIk-WL0UZs2NP7bLvksFgu0YW4Nage_o8_aAWdDMRrXEcdOGzx_nCBXcLmJ7F1hzRqgeojN6Y_NMw_KSsn1EUJhBruV3wPF2Lot_OfHilERhtuqfkxcmA8AV2Hrvo4VVdPvlTk-tRvEhDf1Vv8XHPzpZH1fTnDqrYdGhSJ2_8I2djruCyl4P_i12EjMUjsgw",
    width: 1265
    }
    ],
    place_id: "ChIJKeS-IkrB5zsRMy6qx6RWkhQ",
    rating: 3.8,
    reference: "CoQBcQAAACJ_5-kBHNIRKDa492HAPpJDbAMV1-OQutzkJw9X8_LHto3lzzd7w7ebF13d2RtkSCu-WBlnfczn_zlMDxhdLRdD6QO7yW57WJLfEzx3iRHeYfnDQpG8tNBXp2NrmJ6PcLfK_dSi8aAkRyXbwS7R32ehkwnHyJKR2cRDqaz1eEPjEhAYESuuUptCd_7lX9iCUItXGhTszAXJqVV9QUi9jHmgx9fk0_uNRw",
    scope: "GOOGLE",
    types: [
    "restaurant",
    "food",
    "point_of_interest",
    "establishment"
    ],
    vicinity: "Plot No. 14, Mansarovar Chamber, Sector 17, Vashi, Navi Mumbai"
    },
    {
    geometry: {
    location: {
    lat: 19.0733307,
    lng: 72.9981986
    },
    viewport: {
    northeast: {
    lat: 19.07348189999999,
    lng: 72.99824465
    },
    southwest: {
    lat: 19.0732803,
    lng: 72.99806045
    }
    }
    },
    icon: "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
    id: "9135382dc44c2e61abc863c9f39283b535caf863",
    name: "Navaratna",
    opening_hours: {
    open_now: true,
    weekday_text: [ ]
    },
    photos: [
    {
    height: 2048,
    html_attributions: [
    "<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/116903811673536848139/photos">Fuzail Pathan</a>"
    ],
    photo_reference: "CoQBdwAAAA0kQXGfFHwEBANDa7tLdCt012Zy5m3aav-RCt0YsEhRNvc5RV8GJjXSJ7GXkSBxLZWGn7u1oDf72b3BV4pdVaEpcxzZFmGJbeQA4fsTVpqvMK8A2qatk_5xsYnDA-HplF3dykThaqziic3ZH80n70rGVKH0vRd9ZEqzQqytWFd0EhCyDDteeaERSMQQKm88-v3OGhRXNJKOOTOtu6yW_f8om0X_QRLmgA",
    width: 1536
    }
    ],
    place_id: "ChIJU7AECUrB5zsRYnNux9BXNb4",
    rating: 4.1,
    reference: "CmRdAAAA0uLyL8NVz9kljTLYODyvA7XutYyXmKcDl-7pI1bydnW7ADz23WnNTXLe6tj8Wr76Pn-7IsoWeyDAldqvyo7QXoZn2GyLo80_4ndvRIApZmSM7kWg7ZM2ztgbSqzuKU39EhCnfjaSy6Y7q8Zf9DgKem_cGhR_b0YtqGFyn0lezItsGqwWm3zQgA",
    scope: "GOOGLE",
    types: [
    "restaurant",
    "food",
    "point_of_interest",
    "establishment"
    ],
    vicinity: "Plot 10, Sector 17, Nirman Vyapar Kendra, Vashi, Navi Mumbai"
    },
    {
    geometry: {
    location: {
    lat: 19.073806,
    lng: 72.999681
    },
    viewport: {
    northeast: {
    lat: 19.07449045,
    lng: 72.99975015
    },
    southwest: {
    lat: 19.07357785,
    lng: 72.99965795
    }
    }
    },
    icon: "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
    id: "778f6f9c69b118e89538b6d55ea58053f4b5757c",
    name: "Gupta Sandwiches And Snacks",
    opening_hours: {
    open_now: true,
    weekday_text: [ ]
    },
    photos: [
    {
    height: 705,
    html_attributions: [
    "<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/106854928485883614043/photos">Gupta Sandwiches &amp; Snacks</a>"
    ],
    photo_reference: "CoQBcwAAAMmY7B9CYx5pGp_K-FO86jTAlGmTwveAXBZteVXxoZUAAxDAY95HAffRXQH7_HBuHzAp50fUdpoj4ozjYSJ7w_IGIPIoCFFqhMkX9w0-Ime0bjQGdXQfGn9B9pJhxVuQHQnuvvR62cLtBpm1nI0psTdYquFezpVCpctAbyTZRzDaEhC6cHHl-9xyCzy7dk2T-7JYGhSM7nF-nyIRyqfFRjjp-3Cxcq7H3Q",
    width: 709
    }
    ],
    place_id: "ChIJiTSwAjbB5zsREvIyP49PGl0",
    rating: 3.9,
    reference: "CnRuAAAAv3PACA5hG0IzsCVD_agb1ZHl484UPE-3GR4PLSaj1FtjQBjyHIS0aMHMw3WEmsqf1kVU25H3p64LbAO4hr8VIdiHzSUYb3A0iy42u9cWIMWYUI1BQVjme1l7tjw6z9WKME5iiUM0B2UeXU5kzUrduRIQRAlNEcIaqMqwAW9N5tJBeRoUt-xU5KMF0HVC63_Mzwals9APBt8",
    scope: "GOOGLE",
    types: [
    "meal_takeaway",
    "restaurant",
    "food",
    "point_of_interest",
    "establishment"
    ],
    vicinity: "J.K., JK Chambers Building, Vashi-Turbhe Road, Sector 17, Vashi, Navi Mumbai"
    },
    {
    geometry: {
    location: {
    lat: 19.0737436,
    lng: 72.99694869999999
    }
    },
    icon: "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
    id: "14aa1e7541e5ada2e396fcb8367ddda7c50fba63",
    name: "The Creek",
    opening_hours: {
    open_now: false,
    weekday_text: [ ]
    },
    photos: [
    {
    height: 1717,
    html_attributions: [
    "<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/111737086086789276862/photos">kalpesh bhoir</a>"
    ],
    photo_reference: "CoQBcwAAANPgtFQPbrjuItdS6MsyJdE4zDRgps56TY9TESfpxCdKTkAxFR970QPr4bwF10IZi_hjOD5_MJyxi2csYD6VfzpYk7aEibsnJTWYB8BnclDrDHRrszmnsiJuQp-lgFnebkCNHzlA6SfyjczDbXoYCZDeyuX9vLCXzFGxmfReqVlVEhDnzF1k-xGUwwROMX5KMtJWGhRQJbX2-wnuyN4oKTJQYDeYnTvz1A",
    width: 3052
    }
    ],
    place_id: "ChIJB98RhjXB5zsRDjzrfkSTK6Y",
    rating: 4,
    reference: "CmRdAAAA7PzyIKheZOojK5dxLrpSFYaY5e9SeDVZbjNp5B80_fQ_8hl5EwqXdpH4ay_uKDw4GdxQYkprksl7aVyQv8y21nplqHC7iwvW-d5oxVz7VBnJ-D0lO59EDnQcsGNxDbTDEhCdkdjR9WyT1rZVf0phwLojGhRCiTd96o7dC70kI-v8eT0J2MGf0w",
    scope: "GOOGLE",
    types: [
    "restaurant",
    "food",
    "point_of_interest",
    "establishment"
    ],
    vicinity: "Abbott Hotel, Sector 2, Vashi, Navi Mumbai"
    },
    {
    geometry: {
    location: {
    lat: 19.0728007,
    lng: 72.9983998
    }
    },
    icon: "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
    id: "3f62f559dbf370598141b3da2181a14daf4e21ea",
    name: "Hilton Tandoor Corner",
    opening_hours: {
    open_now: false,
    weekday_text: [ ]
    },
    place_id: "ChIJ94AiEErB5zsReBP3vgUzMbE",
    reference: "CnRpAAAAPX5KIw5LsQKCHZen-6WMTadltS45v39LJkZG9xPTRtIvKwt-ggh1omJ-Adj25mr40ccqygUpNsO9wrk3QimEqaNgawWOk8QUR2XkD_CBqw0tCcJdxoEZzOGOg9b-7pfHq0NJDe0zeyOMOn8aNfdW2hIQ2wwBipzFswfJYIc5bo_jCRoUUXAcBrS31uHDgjsJjkwbM3JU9n8",
    scope: "GOOGLE",
    types: [
    "restaurant",
    "food",
    "point_of_interest",
    "establishment"
    ],
    vicinity: "Plot No 9, Shop-34,Raikar Bhawan, Sector 17, Vashi, Navi Mumbai"
    },
    {
    geometry: {
    location: {
    lat: 19.073837,
    lng: 72.999708
    },
    viewport: {
    northeast: {
    lat: 19.07447585,
    lng: 72.99977174999998
    },
    southwest: {
    lat: 19.07362404999999,
    lng: 72.99968675000001
    }
    }
    },
    icon: "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
    id: "fac14447d42353c83398a3740d27b10ce089426b",
    name: "Bong Adda",
    opening_hours: {
    open_now: false,
    weekday_text: [ ]
    },
    place_id: "ChIJM6CyAzbB5zsROtAbyHKIQPM",
    reference: "CmRdAAAA5PmaXdRsKjPCxpTxUgTN78MFvw_J1QTzWb5I7aEQlav9awOvTqg3xbBC0qjQHMrOkTttAu7PFVpbUSikmhfh0b2CqCWn_Ij-UHgTuCJ_1sD-PY4walHIQt41srU2wU09EhDHrHW4qtXfAToNq6N0ws3-GhTu3tqs-gWSFBf61VNl95dpP9DmKw",
    scope: "GOOGLE",
    types: [
    "restaurant",
    "food",
    "point_of_interest",
    "establishment"
    ],
    vicinity: "Shop No. 33, J.K.Chamber, Vashi-Turbhe Road, Sector 17, Vashi, Navi Mumbai"
    },
    {
    geometry: {
    location: {
    lat: 19.0720287,
    lng: 72.99889189999999
    }
    },
    icon: "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
    id: "431d91810150483c48ed606eee976d690f28e270",
    name: "Fresh",
    place_id: "ChIJ6c6TIUrB5zsRVphiyD-A2_U",
    reference: "CmRZAAAAJ16YoXcMa42tvvdhsggF_yTxjzzVyAWVAiSvFnOWI17pdCOtab0QtQGMF2ULUvSzXcqTD1ARhG07piRVLf9rf9pVLaEtGrxxYIpkhaPm1qbcUNLwj5_8mu1TsZWM2dfzEhDAjKBcCvkXtdEDBQ2Nh-BnGhRThKlW5AvsjI4LpHBQmxKTJ-OyCg",
    scope: "GOOGLE",
    types: [
    "restaurant",
    "food",
    "point_of_interest",
    "establishment"
    ],
    vicinity: "Sector 17, Vashi, Navi Mumbai"
    },
    {
    geometry: {
    location: {
    lat: 19.0721688,
    lng: 72.9966395
    },
    viewport: {
    northeast: {
    lat: 19.07229465,
    lng: 72.99683764999999
    },
    southwest: {
    lat: 19.07212685,
    lng: 72.99654345
    }
    }
    },
    icon: "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
    id: "776662cac5dd2a8bad3cbd53f8050c3d4aa06466",
    name: "Vishwa Lunch Home",
    opening_hours: {
    open_now: true,
    weekday_text: [ ]
    },
    place_id: "ChIJtVauZkrB5zsREtI6oNRm8_g",
    reference: "CnRlAAAA-dRejmzdY7tbM8Ogk-qQEuqWoIFyCzGXnezjPdivhPdVLCH-WrcBoqJ-xfPG2Q4iaqgU15z0enNT3IBY71K8uKF7WqMFozXuFdDjhEtkA5IFPIxhlTjppbj_LDA-dAW7Nf5AbReuzx-08XXLqfDqrxIQPdW1jdL-G1SN7EptklJTURoU7KihYxu2CC-BCe6qFZV5pUaE3Zg",
    scope: "GOOGLE",
    types: [
    "restaurant",
    "food",
    "point_of_interest",
    "establishment"
    ],
    vicinity: "SS-286, MSCB, Mata Vaishnodevi Road, Vashi, Navi Mumbai"
    },
    {
    geometry: {
    location: {
    lat: 19.073718,
    lng: 72.998289
    }
    },
    icon: "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
    id: "d318b7e616e2acbfac8d0bfdc143f85e90b5d2b9",
    name: "Sagar Restaurant & Lounge Bar",
    photos: [
    {
    height: 811,
    html_attributions: [
    "<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/116704626286777632095/photos">Arif Ansari</a>"
    ],
    photo_reference: "CoQBcwAAACpGdRZNf4adOn89lTaJvkqpYRnb-KA2_Z4jyXfutgiKY6159pE3pMcypOgEStysgabK-2xjoAAPzhAFa6vH-9CBZcGTUyPtIzsN7MvhjEGJOTqX9i6mOUDK7-Q5mBrIGNOaz3NmjpKzfO7me4DBnawnOH2Rv6VqCI87bB7_jarBEhCLfi6OihvLuzaGhrFTJS1RGhR52oW8p0sZsBewZ-WWG-_BxA7jjQ",
    width: 448
    }
    ],
    place_id: "ChIJg4MB9zXB5zsREI3nYJfwYyM",
    rating: 4.3,
    reference: "CnRwAAAAnWOyuzcIEHOsPKWVIPS-wVrpQhM7hpvgcZtRqdVQfjabBnkf6DIRBJ8na-98w3dfKz6EhfcApd5QNB9Y9Ie7PCc1pDc_AZiq9VxEc11XiIkGO9FKDAxW64YDio4D_zAsAn1KR7_z5cacymZB1jnA7RIQ4vk146UlDbXHAgdBb7jQvRoUYxCo3-SrvlAllM905-qA2bS07S0",
    scope: "GOOGLE",
    types: [
    "restaurant",
    "food",
    "point_of_interest",
    "establishment"
    ],
    vicinity: "Plot No. 10, Nirman Vyapar, Kendra, Sector 17, Vashi"
    },
    {
    geometry: {
    location: {
    lat: 19.0728007,
    lng: 72.9983998
    }
    },
    icon: "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
    id: "c9fba866dd643560c2ff0b19f902b88243b08964",
    name: "Hilton Tandoor Corner",
    opening_hours: {
    open_now: false,
    weekday_text: [ ]
    },
    photos: [
    {
    height: 356,
    html_attributions: [
    "<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/116592040285484829369/photos">Hilton Tandoor Corner</a>"
    ],
    photo_reference: "CoQBcwAAALAAwM2eGjZZd4-V2eSKrV90g9M2xdhnSHNRa0MobY4NJ4t1WIgUFlHg3EgQ32xYdX3Ox0zK7M6rv11RisVTag2bGYGj1nX4fsbVXvz3R0aT1JRzjH_bpfP2QCnITK5ZtxAcCqFHlcQFGyAH2Uw3h8sHx9BG4MJ7LFvYh_HEmhOhEhDNKtcmECfdCurzwt6hIJoIGhSFdFDQFUDIQFYVUiu79zMEMkE1jg",
    width: 356
    }
    ],
    place_id: "ChIJJ8gdEErB5zsRUbzQkWm7eTg",
    reference: "CnRoAAAAwrJvqfvyIxzDmwfOUAnBmZQkizuuAeUUCYdgUFieg1ifFUVRIBJy9oxCs55_WLYPGJuh4K9iJF9OVnXFearB19S8Mv_L79mZtu3-WGHYAabjMYdxA-P66YZgSfrm_cHpRgIDK3nco-U8gFMAi4iWlhIQvBFVmM_rgVAyV85b5N-ZSRoU5HgCdDI2D352U0i8W3tMmcDNL6g",
    scope: "GOOGLE",
    types: [
    "restaurant",
    "food",
    "point_of_interest",
    "establishment"
    ],
    vicinity: "Plot No 9 Shop-34,Raikar Bhawan,, Sector 17, Vashi, Navi Mumbai"
    },
    {
    geometry: {
    location: {
    lat: 19.072145,
    lng: 72.99742049999999
    }
    },
    icon: "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
    id: "7f078347c5edffe07e198b9de2219b68228a32c5",
    name: "Only Rolls",
    place_id: "ChIJl7VWakrB5zsR9rvobQT0ULM",
    reference: "CmReAAAAjK5z_inAZlgGOlvP-8Y95-Nxjtbj9r3XbUtEU0wjgeLB3QSgioTzKOeRcffBf4RVKn1zo1PVDgwzU6ULmN3NoHYq-nHTLULuLTqxWyDNBTl3bZ7ujDj_5eQnGWgoaKN7EhAo5Jglhba3foqqTN51tl8hGhTcjPMxs0uq9i_LMcYmb6nohn-krA",
    scope: "GOOGLE",
    types: [
    "meal_takeaway",
    "restaurant",
    "food",
    "point_of_interest",
    "establishment"
    ],
    vicinity: "Vashi, Navi Mumbai"
    },
    {
    geometry: {
    location: {
    lat: 19.0719983,
    lng: 72.99875779999999
    }
    },
    icon: "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
    id: "5a7a4a861f83da1a415bd5523a77935257796c5c",
    name: "Kwality Roll`s",
    place_id: "ChIJJZg5IkrB5zsRXDUBeB0Okq4",
    reference: "CnRiAAAAz_Via8ujArIFfW7gMe6ThUzuvCcUPASWjITD1vdUEX2vYY04XPxsX9uodk5jKWg06hCvkSHQSvnnRDFfxq1WdrdVmjvrHYNxLJ5dc25Y3XndkEbo7nFZHWtRbJZy8YkyW8xiqpb35ffmn-3Sq-0xiRIQzgsEl6tZjMB_qtQv1oUSfxoUdcre34EtvfI4q83Ck88ho9vpju8",
    scope: "GOOGLE",
    types: [
    "restaurant",
    "food",
    "point_of_interest",
    "establishment"
    ],
    vicinity: "Sector 17, Vashi, Navi Mumbai"
    },
    {
    geometry: {
    location: {
    lat: 19.072873,
    lng: 72.99523099999999
    },
    viewport: {
    northeast: {
    lat: 19.072879,
    lng: 72.99530005
    },
    southwest: {
    lat: 19.0728662,
    lng: 72.99516745
    }
    }
    },
    icon: "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
    id: "38ad344deade66b5e656e0fb9935c0e175cca5aa",
    name: "Gupta Fast Food",
    opening_hours: {
    open_now: true,
    weekday_text: [ ]
    },
    photos: [
    {
    height: 1280,
    html_attributions: [
    "<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/112881966645802156177/photos">Akash Gupta</a>"
    ],
    photo_reference: "CoQBcwAAAG9osAsb6v1mPNixkKvoIAwq5sOk8Ot1I6VCKfiyxWl3E5hh1EHuQO7E5F3PJH-Qi28qfmRsETYbdZIapJkefB47usAHIBKDSc8y-b5dl8vFSc7mMGCQLkwa_6ytsXsiiV1ces8Esg3b06vLjur_vlb85ogJDzPwu17qLjTJRyDNEhBUXAH0SRZQI8vdubp7H2tsGhQHMatRD-TrIPmZFE56PJEqqfwK_Q",
    width: 960
    }
    ],
    place_id: "ChIJ7boKnErB5zsRcLByU8_ifk8",
    rating: 4.1,
    reference: "CnRiAAAAYXze-X_VJA9Xtq28zBA5Gd9uOz4FaQhXcj5Kki0x8fKUEC7wqg8_4ERDEnVW_8SNPQAOkKyNjLByfbYvQijh9qrNCXYxadY4r-fVkAjG4dgizHhS8af83N9jgHjIN0i45XjXL6xM63B7-r4nnrZOlhIQThIIJLtHCjkj6aifviamExoUqPtaVKan-mg6bZwzvp-9iwWQ9L8",
    scope: "GOOGLE",
    types: [
    "restaurant",
    "food",
    "point_of_interest",
    "establishment"
    ],
    vicinity: "Shop No. 37, SS-3, Premnath Maruti Patil Marg, Vashi, Navi Mumbai"
    },
    {
    geometry: {
    location: {
    lat: 19.0708339,
    lng: 72.9979087
    }
    },
    icon: "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
    id: "369ceb5d9d54df0e34982817d57350dd333e89a1",
    name: "Domino's Pizza",
    opening_hours: {
    open_now: false,
    weekday_text: [ ]
    },
    photos: [
    {
    height: 972,
    html_attributions: [
    "<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/118296989547144280176/photos">Gaurav Dhapola</a>"
    ],
    photo_reference: "CoQBcwAAAEstSNItXHgjkkWxMD0qu1peeAKZnz5Pl1uWv1Ixu9vXT2xqA_AFQBa9_KGnDFfXvOI9_NpZR80Jh5EAdrERQ7ryHYo4CW1Co_Y4-hHgfGiTNrMwPCskWjVkMsrvbqv64JV57l7ZRGSPlsUFCRtNHYzqsPKN5H3NZpJj9bpIcgK8EhDdRxi2XH1miMuTbVFw80VTGhSim03Al0b999TNh0th2OArWdTGCg",
    width: 1296
    }
    ],
    place_id: "ChIJ346uNUrB5zsRnlCSsvjy-FY",
    price_level: 1,
    rating: 4.3,
    reference: "CnRhAAAA5vb6NW9qoG8C32p6nwXL0YlMW9GxA9p5hpEvMk6upn76iTHkpfQmYI_594be9znNrqFAaANClbRYbDhzdkQEcp-MAH-XOg7H5JX-bQgkOgkEa7KCObaks5rcZsM-FRg-WnpKcoK6XelAAp_Oc8C6fxIQHN2K5sxAhUGjLUACB6krfxoUSgu063j1I5e0BHIrmCQB34T6KRU",
    scope: "GOOGLE",
    types: [
    "meal_delivery",
    "restaurant",
    "food",
    "point_of_interest",
    "establishment"
    ],
    vicinity: "Unit No. 1, Plot No. 4, Ground Floor, Arenja Commercial Complex, Sector 17, Vashi, Mumbai"
    },
    {
    geometry: {
    location: {
    lat: 19.0708175,
    lng: 72.9967858
    }
    },
    icon: "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
    id: "0382a54ce02870347f829599b6835776eb822943",
    name: "Maharastra Restaurant",
    opening_hours: {
    open_now: false,
    weekday_text: [ ]
    },
    place_id: "ChIJh83SU0rB5zsRR4jBiaNn9q8",
    reference: "CnRpAAAA5O1LPNDgJP-fXOnYVpw1EzxNf-yWnyxDPFPhrmE1ljqhFlSa7L9b2_5cf1YmYkR_eWMEA25g5OsQ06ZFmZPKfFbMHqrNyCFD88bygmrlwf__6qbZHBsXvBg9mty5kA2bkaIN_KbtUoKiRbcDf1ubixIQ2kXlIQ2UdU9TFkyrfncVghoUDtU9YbDuQnPukA-tJ2wph0Ng8QU",
    scope: "GOOGLE",
    types: [
    "restaurant",
    "bar",
    "food",
    "point_of_interest",
    "establishment"
    ],
    vicinity: "Shop No. G-8, Lokmanya Tilak Market, Opposite Apna bazar, Sector 1, Vashi, Navi Mumbai"
    },
    {
    geometry: {
    location: {
    lat: 19.073485,
    lng: 72.994654
    }
    },
    icon: "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
    id: "38844ab0a6a88a0a53578685239a1b129db1a6a7",
    name: "Vicious Circle Kitchen & Bar",
    opening_hours: {
    open_now: false,
    weekday_text: [ ]
    },
    photos: [
    {
    height: 3120,
    html_attributions: [
    "<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/114638265574709267282/photos">Ashok Chavan</a>"
    ],
    photo_reference: "CoQBcwAAAJAMtPN7R2EaofVw5yb8mxH-fPLoZGjr7vEm0hT8x9_r_wjtjLtLcligda62m5cjSVtxa42-I0E68fhLp_hUTBWzhmj63mamRSxXbXJ2b6oQPwd5IudsIvWuIRHQ2YJwYMKtBAXuOgnkCTEKAWpG7dU0smCTW1cGRAzVNxHrDvXqEhAwsgJBJephJvBim_MFuipEGhTDYW-hOOubFIFWOcb5k6690yBhyQ",
    width: 4160
    }
    ],
    place_id: "ChIJexFuXjXB5zsR02Aj9far5jU",
    rating: 4.5,
    reference: "CnRvAAAAMU22Wv_nCK9MilwBc9rnhWswF5JQI6z_zUQfetG8P30OupjlvsyzRnkW8IvcLbD3V-RPg-Lg6tL60-1bFNmPjyPnXP3EzvXgDnEFEdJ_ARdmxHplPOiRf2Frg0UentEW6P97RbJLyFw3_4rdfkqgahIQLqfykiR9agpOkX8TTYoEJBoUfO7d0qdesUEU0Z0unSWfm6HXY3I",
    scope: "GOOGLE",
    types: [
    "restaurant",
    "food",
    "point_of_interest",
    "establishment"
    ],
    vicinity: "No 1 and 2, F Type Bldg, Sec 7, Vashi"
    },
    {
    geometry: {
    location: {
    lat: 19.0738015,
    lng: 73.0017051
    }
    },
    icon: "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
    id: "db2f5cb8b1fbe6cd044ccd4fb01fd00d0e0c1276",
    name: "Vishwa Jyoti",
    opening_hours: {
    open_now: true,
    weekday_text: [ ]
    },
    photos: [
    {
    height: 1536,
    html_attributions: [
    "<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/106912138689800638266/photos">Anand Deo</a>"
    ],
    photo_reference: "CoQBdwAAAOezpwgQIk5TWhRJCTN_W5qgTLZ3ndKpq4_V2DInhlPNvgqniC8gn8AtaDMUpX5OpPamIrEQ4jJeTarz6iDmgTQ27t_1mGNUWDvuen6E0Sym-KK_OAs8GzZrSkdL-Xwbds71cUaKNLNvUa_pt1OLd7EaiXJUh9EnZh6uwWIwT4HcEhAT9xpTuZjDe-Da-YaI-8x-GhR1X552RfyR2xn7nfBl0owE15dDbA",
    width: 2048
    }
    ],
    place_id: "ChIJ8fLzKTbB5zsRcBCy_jbD4s4",
    rating: 4.2,
    reference: "CmRgAAAAHz2EJ9XpYrZnhDyJdmPeq9KWPP81LNtYTswuU9ZthrzpLC4il4IlxCR--nDDF2ZEFEWdgTpwRFNaPRoHtI0fdXlsBEM3YdmPuyb3OH8n1kOQfAfrVFSMeu-mKcheaMxTEhCe3BR1hysZeohL4Jkfa2zOGhQZKkAPdplrsQ_-nnhGOozFJRmjIA",
    scope: "GOOGLE",
    types: [
    "restaurant",
    "food",
    "point_of_interest",
    "establishment"
    ],
    vicinity: "Shiv Center Building Sector 17, Vashi, Mumbai"
    },
    {
    geometry: {
    location: {
    lat: 19.0723058,
    lng: 73.0006774
    }
    },
    icon: "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
    id: "4e2bc9337daf24227e37ca9e136aeb6123b686b6",
    name: "Garcia's Famous Pizza",
    place_id: "ChIJ____v0nB5zsREvdvWkEgdAw",
    reference: "CnRoAAAAa37ic3dsH2gAItAWIKOofvssPHM5rZrgSbLdWZK1uRjQEL9fPczks3McTMrdh01vgnu5YOyARn-Y3hU5CUx8_1rn_LFf-pXzlwQZo7jgqUMpTK7qAqj1tKtl9sH8w0qOkxyvIBKlDj6Lte8iVrXa8RIQq6bfYtVTHyzysox8yTUeTBoUl_9xBSEmuUFXDJ5KKXEbliZOmwI",
    scope: "GOOGLE",
    types: [
    "restaurant",
    "food",
    "point_of_interest",
    "establishment"
    ],
    vicinity: "Shop No. 5, Plot No. 3, Ground Floor, Om Rachana Society, Vashi, Sector-17, Mumbai"
    },
    {
    geometry: {
    location: {
    lat: 19.0732968,
    lng: 73.0018098
    }
    },
    icon: "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
    id: "c4e64ee90f1cd5fccb9f05d340c91f79d4d03f86",
    name: "Maroosh Vashi",
    opening_hours: {
    open_now: false,
    weekday_text: [ ]
    },
    place_id: "ChIJZRVR0knB5zsRvy8-y0ke2aY",
    rating: 3.8,
    reference: "CnRhAAAAXS9xEC0AcaPsF3_qbVhA5sOJyvvAjNrWQ3arHPVvRiVJOJ9SRsg3bqNM_fRnNWh_avcRGlH0OejzYxYoGHymTzWdgYBWlFHbK44CtMxdYCZxuign8Gl__R2FsnygW5cU9WoobMzBEgn09K5zAq1lJRIQkVSYwXCnVvEo30WPLl7jHxoUFoFLfz-DeK7-Zvvl22Bz8dMATKc",
    scope: "GOOGLE",
    types: [
    "restaurant",
    "food",
    "point_of_interest",
    "establishment"
    ],
    vicinity: "Shop No. 1, Arenja Corner, Next to Airtel Gallery, Sector 17, Vashi, Navi Mumbai"
    },
    {
    geometry: {
    location: {
    lat: 19.069406,
    lng: 72.998522
    }
    },
    icon: "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
    id: "84385b435c1f9b266160d8a1cf146d045a0e24c3",
    name: "Shree Ganesh",
    opening_hours: {
    open_now: true,
    weekday_text: [ ]
    },
    place_id: "ChIJi34n3UvB5zsRO3oCMq43eu0",
    reference: "CmRgAAAAGFWIrBOvQNJ1raUwcqKYrSo43hWf9AZlMvcNouUzfetFkPjMnW0RdB7va2F-P_qNO8tKE1-nT41p_Pk-_0MWrVfMf5IRwSwEFETbHzrpTpOnpQj6T8V8qY3wx4IOJk--EhBqoWwzBJXu8HHHcNQMMJV0GhTjaxDVFO6KqJuPNoOsUc4jLCm_aQ",
    scope: "GOOGLE",
    types: [
    "restaurant",
    "food",
    "point_of_interest",
    "establishment"
    ],
    vicinity: "112, C Wing, Vashi Plaza, Sector-17, Vashi, Navi Mumbai"
    }
    ],
    status: "OK"
    }
    results[0].opening_hours+-View sourceoptions
```

Comment: Are you facing an issue in parsing JSON or getting JSON from server?

Comment: Additional to @PareshMayani's question, the `Exception` implies that the JSON passed to the parser is empty (0 length). Is the JSON that you've shared the JSON received from the server?

Comment: No, this is not the JSON from the server guys. The content string variable is null in the above code.

Comment: Your JSON is invalid under most RFCs. Assuming `results[0].opening_hours+-View sourceoptions` is not even part of the file. Can you check that your `bufferedReader` already have content? It is likely that you received any reply from server (such as 300, 404, 500) and the document is empty, thus `while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)` starts as true

Answer (score 0):

I guess u r getting `NULL` while printing the response contents. You can use below to get the `JSON` response and then print the response.

```
url = new URL(YOUR_URL);
conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
conn.connect();

InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();

StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
int ch = -1;

while ( (ch=in.read()) != -1){
   buffer.append((char) ch);
}

System.out.println("response = " + buffer.toString());
```

Thats it. Give it a try.

Comment: I am getting cannot resolve method error. 
the error is for the readLine method method on in object

Comment: @nerd.post: hey I tried ur code and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @nerd.post: I have read ur edit but I don't now wts wrong so I have corrected my code incase u wanna try coz ur code did worked at my side.

Answer (score 0):

I had missed to use the Async class to call the google places API . 
Because of which I was getting an network error , prior to getting this above error.